# Samsung T260 1920x1200 streched

Tags: windows-8, resolution

I have Windows 8 64 Bits and a monitor Samsung T260 (Analog) the native resolution is 1920x1200 but when I try this resolution I get a left black bar on the screen and the image is stretched.

How I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is an "auto-adjust" function that you can use with the analog connection.  That will fix both the distortion and alignment issues.

From [Samsung's website](http://support-us.samsung.com/cyber/popup/iframe/pop_troubleshooting_fr.jsp?idx=139132&modelname=T260&modelcode=&session_id=NlT7JJKJm13XGQJhJJ52tTmTDJhsQvyMj2QnpL2TnmdGP9fkKGhF!549360580!1761676348!7501!-1!201436002!1761676444!7501!-1!1298517627415):

> **T260 Perform An Auto Adjustment** If your monitor has graphics or text that are fuzzy, this may be due to an incorrect monitor setting.
>
> **To perform an Auto Adjustment**
>
> To perform an Auto Adjustment, follow these steps:
>   1. Power on your monitor, and boot up your computer.
>   2. Press the [Auto] button on your monitor.
>   3. The Auto Adjustment indicator appears. When the Auto Adjustment windows disappears, the auto adjusting process is complete.
>
> If after performing each troubleshooting step above, the graphics or
>   text remain fuzzy.
>
> - [Click here](http://support-us.samsung.com/cyber/popup/pop_troubleshooting.jsp?modelname=T260&idx=135413) to Turn On ClearType. (For Windows XP and Vista Users)
> - Try connecting your monitor to a computer with a different graphics card and see if that end the problem. On rare occasions, fuzzy images
>     are caused by the graphics card.
>
> The Auto Adjustment Button on your monitor is the second button from
>   the bottom along the right-hand side. The Auto Adjustment feature
>   automatically adjusts the fine, coarse, and position on your monitor
>   to the incoming video signal.
>
> [image: picture of monitor buttons]
>
> **Note:** If you have are using the Digital (DVI) connection on your LCD monitor, Auto Adjust will not work when your monitor is set to
>   this mode. Instead, you adjust the image through the Windows Display
>   Properties, or through the Advance Settings provided with your
>   graphics card. For information on accessing the Advance Settings of
>   your graphics card, review the documentation provided by the
>   manufacture of your graphics card or the manufacture of your computer.

Comment: http://www.manualowl.com/m/Samsung/T260HD/Manual/43451 - The manual mentions a `position` in the menu, on page 37

Comment: I've pressed that button one thousand times. In lunux i need append a custom resolution with CVT adn Xrandr but in windows i dont have this tools